# "require is not defined" error comes when i try to import js file (with node modules) to my main electron js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

This is my folder folder structure [image]

Hi im new to **electron.js** I was facing for an issue where that i cannot capture jquery events in my **main.js**  file. As a solution i created a separate file (**events.js**)[now i can capture jquery events] and i connect it to **index.html**. So in my **event.js** i added a **cron-job(node-cron)** to check whether it's working or not, but when i try to run a project i get an error saying **require is not defined**. Without any import library , it worked.  [image]

This is my **index.html**

```
    <body>
    <div style="margin-top:15px" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block" href="./layouts/settings.html" id="menu-btn-settings"
                    role="button">Settings</a>
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block" href="./layouts/health.html" id="menu-btn-health"
                    role="button">System Health</a>
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block" href="./layouts/abc-now.html" id="menu-btn-abc-now"
                    role="button">Sync Now</a>
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block" href="./layouts/abc-customer.html" id="menu-btn-abc-user"
                    role="button">Sync
                    Customer</a>
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block" href="./layouts/about.html" id="menu-btn-about"
                    role="button">About</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <div id="alert-msg"></div>
                <div id="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Insert this line above script imports  -->
    <script>if (typeof module === 'object') { window.module = module; module = undefined; }</script>

    <script src="./assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    //
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
    <script src="./app/events.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/require.js"></script>


    <script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>


</body>
```

This is **my main.js**

```
 app.on('ready', function () {
    win = new BrowserWindow({});
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
        },
    }));

    win.on('closed', function () {
        app.quit();
    });

    win.webContents.openDevTools();

});
```

this is my **event.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
    var job = new CronJob('* * * * * *', function () {
        console.log('You will see this message every second');
    }, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
    job.start();
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
```

Remove `webPreferences` from `win.loadURL` and add to `BrowserWindow` option. The below is the sample code to enable the Node api in `BrowserWindow`

```
// Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved me